# Testing with React's Jest and Enzyme when async componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

- react:16.3.0-alpha.1
- jest: "22.3.0"
- enzyme: 3.3.0
- typescript: 2.7.1

code:

```
class Foo extends React.PureComponent<undefined,undefined>{
   bar:number;
   async componentDidMount() {
     this.bar = 0;
     let echarts = await import('echarts'); // async import
     this.bar = 100;
   }
}
```

test:

```
describe('...', () => {
  test('...', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo/>);
    const instance = await wrapper.instance();
    expect(instance.bar).toBe(100);
  });
});
```

Error:

```
Expected value to be:
  100
Received:
  0
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solution:

1: use the async/await syntax.

2: Use mount (no shallow).

3: await async componentLifecycle.

For ex:

```
    test(' ',async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(
         <Foo />
      );
      await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
    })
```

Comment: This is not what you were trying to check in your question posted above.My answer is the right solution to your problem.

Comment: This will cause the method to run twice.

Comment: @VivekN has the right solution. This will run "componentDidMount" twice. Any await after mounting will probably "solve" the problem, but it's not the right solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 17):

Something like this should work for you:-

```
 describe('...', () => {
   test('...', async () => {
     const wrapper = await mount(<Foo/>);
     expect(wrapper.instance().bar).toBe(100);
   });
 });
```

Comment: This was the best solution for me, particularly as I didn't want to shallow mount

Comment: Indeed; and if you have a `setState` in the component's `didMount`, you'll need to add `wrapper.update();` before the `expect`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
it('should do something', async function() {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
  await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
  app.update();
  expect(wrapper.instance().bar).toBe(100);
});
```

Comment: After looking through google on this problem and trying to implement async componentDidMount through mount's enzyme. And "mount" way is not fit for react native project - I had a lot mistakes. This method helped me. And you don't need to install jsdom and use mount. "react": "16.4.1", "react-native": "0.56.0", "enzyme": "^3.4.4", "jest": "23.5.0"

Comment: what's app here?

Comment: @Pavan I think `wrapper.update()` was intended. [--ref](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html)

Comment: btw, `await` won't do anything there unless your `componentDidMount()` returns a promise

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions provided here fixed all my issues. At the end I found https://medium.com/@lucksp_22012/jest-enzyme-react-testing-with-async-componentdidmount-7c4c99e77d2d which fixed my problems.

**Summary**

```
function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}

it('should do someting', async () => {
    const wrapper = await mount(<Foo/>);
    await flushPromises();

    expect(wrapper.instance().bar).toBe(100);
});
```

Comment: For anybody looking at this, use setTimeout instead of setImmediate.

Answer (score 0):

Your test also needs to implement async, await.
For ex:

```
  it('should do something', async function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
    const result = await wrapper.instance();
    expect(result.bar).toBe(100);
  });
```

Comment: edited, have you tried the await when you execute the instance?, The await basically operates on a promise

Comment: if you can share your complete test

Comment: I don't think `.instance()` returns a promise, so I don't think `await` is doing anything there. `TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).then is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jest.useFakeTimers();` then you need to use

```
await jest.runAllTimersAsync();
```

instead of the flushPromises solution