# jest mock multiple axios call

Tags: mocking, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'd like to mock and assert API calls defined in ComponentDidMount.

```
// App.js    
async componentDidMount() {
        await this.props.actions.getAnnexList();
        await this.props.actions.getTariffCalendar();
      }
```

I create **mocks** folder with axios.js file.

```
// __mocks__/axios.js
export default {
  get: jest.fn(),
  post: jest.fn(),
};
```

Here is my test suite. I'd like to assert second API call. I put some console.log() in each API action so I know renderComponent() invoke both calls (CDM). I expect to mockAxios be called 2 times but my test failed (it was called 1 time). So my question is how to mock axios to assert multiple calls in one test?

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import '@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each';
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../App';

import store from '../../store/configureStore';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import mockAxios from 'axios';


/** Render component connected to redux-store */
const renderComponent = () =>
  render(
    <Provider store={store()}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
  );

describe('App', () => {
  it('get data on CDM (getAnnexList, getTariffCalendar)', () => {
    mockAxios.post
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(getAnnexList) // first call
      .mockResolvedValueOnce(getTariffCalendar); // second call

    const {} = renderComponent();

    expect(mockAxios.post).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'http://localhost/OrderTrancheData/GetAnnexList',
      {
        af: null,
      },
      requestConfig, // mocking some headers etc.
    );
   // assert 2nd call

  });
}
```

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003144/testing-async-componentdidmount-with-jest-react-testing-library and if you're following the react-testing-library practices, IMHO you should be asserting what the user will see after those calls not that the calls were done per se

Comment: I understand react-testing-library practices but in some cases I'd like to assert how many times my component fetched data. I noticed if I remove async/await from componentDidMount I get expected 2 API calls.